# Travis - how do I merge some files from another branch of the same repo?

Tags: git, branch, travis-ci

At a certain point in my Travis-CI deployment process I want to merge a set of files from a different branch in the same repo.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this.  Simply setting up a bash script to run commands like `git checkout origin master` gives me errors like:

```
error: pathspec 'origin' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So my question is: how can I get my hands on files from another branche in Travis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Travis is not aware of other branches on origin and doesn't have copies of them locally.  You have to run `git fetch` to resolve this:

`git fetch --depth=1 git@github.com:your-org/your-repo.git refs/heads/other-branch:refs/remotes/origin/other-branch`

This command tells `git fetch` to copy the branch at `refs/heads/other-branch` to the local machine at `refs/remotes/origin/other-branch`

Once you've done this you will then be able to get your hands on files from `other-branch` using standard git commands.

Answer (score 0):

Remote branches are referred to like this: the-remote/the-branch... so you need to say something like: `git checkout origin/master`. It also works for a lot (if not all?) operations.... diff, cherry-pick, rebase, merge, etc etc

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that also - I get a similar error

Comment: What is the error? And what is the output of ```git branch -a```?

Comment: Also.... if you want to get your hands on files from another branch, you could either cherry-pick the revisions where they are being added/modified (if you have been tracking their history correctly) or you can do this: ```git checkout <revision> -- <path>```. Revision is a revision ID, a branch a tag. path is the path that you want to put into your working tree.

Comment: `git branch -a` only shows the current branch and detached head version of the current branch -- I put something in another answer which seems to work for me.